# Enviar Datos de un formulario html a un archivo php

Tags: php, html5, post

Cómo van ?, les comento, estoy haciendo un formulario para recolectar unos datos y luego enviarlos a una BD. El problema que tengo es que al parecer los datos del formulario no se estan enviando al archivo .php, digo esto porque dentro del archivo .php mando a imprimir las variables que contienen los datos del formulario y no imprimen nada. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Este es el código del formulario.

```
 <!-- Contact -->
  <section class="page-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Contacto</h2>
          <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted"><font color="white">CONTÁCTANOS Y HAREMOS TUS PROYECTOS DIGITALES UNA REALIDAD</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <form id="contactForm" action="cargue_datos.php" method="POST" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate" >
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="txtNombre" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="txtEmail" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="txtTelefono" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Telefono *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="txtMensaje" id="message" placeholder="Dejanos tu Mensaje  *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="success"></div>
                <button name="btn_enviar_mensaje" id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Los datos que estoy tratando de enviar son el Nombre, Email, Telefono y un Mensaje.

```
<?php

//Se invoca al archivo conexion
//include './php/conexion.php';

//$con = Conectar();


//Se realizan las validaciones

//if ($_POST){//['btn_enviar_mensaje'])) {
    /*if ($_POST['txtNombre'] == '' or $_POST['txtEmail'] == '' or $_POST['txtTelefono'] == '' or $_POST['txtMensaje']) {
        echo "No puedes dejar los datos vacíos";
    }else{*/
        //Asigno los elementos gráficos a las variables
        @$nombre = $_POST['txtNombre'];
        @$email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
        @$telefono = $_POST['txtTelefono'];
        @$mensaje = $_POST['txtMensaje'];

        echo "Hola";

        echo $nombre, $email, $telefono, $mensaje;
        /*
        //Cargo los datos  a la BD
        $consulta = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO contacto(nombre, correo, telefono, mensaje) 
        VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$email."', '".$telefono."', '".$mensaje."')") or die (mysqli_error());
*/

    //}
//}

?>
```

Comment: Estas usando ajax para conectar el front con el back?

Comment: No amigo, no estoy usando Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @Permomo he probado el código que has publicado, no me marca errores y me imprime las variables enviadas, descomenté la sentencia `if ($_POST){//['btn_enviar_mensaje']))` y en ese caso no me imprimió ninguna variable por lo que cambie un poco el código de `cargue_datos.php`:

```
<?php

//Se invoca al archivo conexion
//include './php/conexion.php';

//$con = Conectar();


//Se realizan las validaciones

if (isset($_POST['btn_enviar_mensaje'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['txtNombre']) or empty($_POST['txtEmail']) or empty($_POST['txtTelefono']) or empty($_POST['txtMensaje'])) {
        echo "No puedes dejar los datos vacíos";
    }else{
        //Asigno los elementos gráficos a las variables
        @$nombre = $_POST['txtNombre'];
        @$email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
        @$telefono = $_POST['txtTelefono'];
        @$mensaje = $_POST['txtMensaje'];

        echo "Hola";

        echo $nombre, $email, $telefono, $mensaje;

        //Cargo los datos  a la BD
        // $consulta = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO contacto(nombre, correo, telefono, mensaje) 
        // VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$email."', '".$telefono."', '".$mensaje."')") or die (mysqli_error());


    }
}

?>
```

Espero te sirva.